# Angular 17, bootstrap V5.3 [attr.data-bs-title] not showing tooltip

Tags: angular, bootstrap-5

I am making an application in Angular version 17 where I want to show a tooltip. The content of the tooltip will be dynamic, this will be supplied by a `@Input()` into the component.
While a normal static tooltip will show up just fine, the moment I try to make the content of the tooltip dynamic it won't show up anymore.

Below the code of the html file;

```
<!-- not working but desired -->
<span class="d-inline-block ms-2" tabindex="0" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" [attr.data-bs-title]="'toolTipText'">
  <fa-icon [icon]="faCirleInfo" *ngIf="hasToolTipTextValue"/>
</span>

<!-- working, but not desired -->
<span class="d-inline-block ms-5" tabindex="0" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement='auto' data-bs-title="'Disabled tooltip'">
  <fa-icon [icon]="faCirleInfo" *ngIf="hasToolTipTextValue"/>
</span>
```

Below the code of the .ts file of set component

```
export class TextInputControlComponent implements OnInit{
@Input() labelText?: string;
@Input() toolTipText?: string;
@Input() controlId?: string;

form!: FormGroup;
hasToolTipTextValue!: Boolean;  
faCirleInfo: any;

constructor(private rootFormGroup: FormGroupDirective){}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.form = this.rootFormGroup.form;
  this.hasToolTipTextValue = this.toolTipText !== undefined;
  this.faCirleInfo = faCircleInfo;    

  var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs- 
  toggle="tooltip"]'))
  var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
  });
}
```

It seems when I use a directive for data-bs-title it stops working.
So `data-bs-title="help"` works, but `[attr.data-bs-title="'help'"]` won't work.

Also `[attr.title]="'help'"` does work, but won't take the bootstrap styling. While just doing `title="help"` (which is just the same thing?) does take the bootstrap styling.

Anyone encountered this problem before and maybe has a solution for this issue or has another solution for the desired result?

Comment: `data-bs-toggle` will not work without bootstrap js files. Have you included those? Better approach would be to use a dedicated library: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home

Answer (score 0):

as @robert suggested in the comments I started using https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home for this functionality and this works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move tooltip initialization in [ngAfterViewInit()](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit) hook instead, when the view is initialized:

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
      var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
      return new Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
      });    
  }
```

**[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-17-starter-project-wkbz4y?file=src%2Fmy-component%2Fmy-component.component.ts)**